# Am I flagging too many posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, moderation

Today I was reviewing some questions and answers made by new users, and honestly speaking some of the answers were not even answers at all, most (if not all) of the answers I've seen were just *"one line"* answers which could have easily been a comment.

Of course I brought attention to these questions and answers by flagging them, but now I've just reached my flagging limit (12) so I'm wondering if I've actually done any good or is it a bad thing simply because I need so many flags.

Comment: That's not a bad thing at all. It means you contributed to SO's quality control mechanism to the full extent of what's available to you!

Comment: Note that one-answer posts that *could* have been posted as comments are usually *still answers*. Do not flag those as Not An Answer, because those flags will generally be declined. Only use NAA for posts that are not attempts to answer (such as 'I have this problem too' or 'Hi jimmy, how is the class going for you?').

Comment: Do note that as you flag stuff, successful flags will give you more flags up to 100 flags.  I know people that use all 100 flags each day.  12 flags is not too much.

Comment: You should have seen how many flags were cast by some of the people who are now moderators. I don't think any of them will complain about volume, just accuracy.

Comment: Keep in mind that simply being short does not prevent something from being an answer, and that we're specifically discouraged from answering in comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no problem with flagging if you're flagging with good intentions as you're trying to help improve the quality of the site. Just make sure your flagging is accurate, which will improve over time.

Take a look at your flag summary: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/5870134/

If the majority are accepted, carry on. If you get a bunch of declined/disputed flags, try to learn from them... and carry on.

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciate it.